# Measuring similarity using RMSE

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, similarity, mse

I have the following data as follows:

| object | l2a | l2b | l4 | l5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.6649 | 0.5916 | 0.033569 | 0.557373 |
| b | 0.8421 | 0.5132 | 0.000000 | 0.697193 |
| c | 0.6140 | 0.2807 | 0.084217 | 0.650313 |
| d | 0.7619 | 0.3810 | 0.000000 | 0.662306 |
| e | 0.6957 | 0.3043 | 0.000000 | 0.645135 |

Is it possible to measure the similarity between (a-b), (a-c), (a-d), (a-e), (b-c), ..., (d,e) using RMSE?

For example:

Similarity between object a (_a) and object b (_b):

```
diff_l2a = l2a_a - l2a_b

diff_l2b = l2b_a - l2b_b

diff_l4 = l4_a - l4_b

diff_l5 = l5_a - l5_b
```

Then calculate the RMSE:

```
RMSEs = [RMSE(diff_l2a, diff_l2b), RMSE(diff_l2a, diff_l4), RMSE(diff_l2a, diff_l5), ..., RMSE(diff_l4, diff_l5)]
```

Similarity:

```
average(RMSEs)
```

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but did you look at various distance metrics? I'd say that choosing one of those would be a more usual approach, although RMSE is quite similar to an L2 norm (Euclidean distance). Or maybe cosine distance would suit your situation better, or some other metric.

Comment: I implemented it below, I hope it works what u want.

Comment: I intend to compare the similarity results between the distance metrics, hence, I would like to know if it is possible to use RMSE to measure the similarity. @MattHall

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that. @ÖmerSezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RMSE Similarity DF Code part:**

```
num_objects = len(df)
sim_matrix = np.zeros((num_objects, num_objects))

for i in range(num_objects):
    for j in range(i + 1, num_objects):
        rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(attributes[i], attributes[j]))
        sim_matrix[i, j] = rmse
        sim_matrix[j, i] = rmse
```

**Code (with DF):**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

data = {
    'object': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'l2a': [0.6649, 0.8421, 0.6140, 0.7619, 0.6957],
    'l2b': [0.5916, 0.5132, 0.2807, 0.3810, 0.3043],
    'l4': [0.033569, 0.0, 0.084217, 0.0, 0.0],
    'l5': [0.557373, 0.697193, 0.650313, 0.662306, 0.645135]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
attributes = df.iloc[:, 1:].values

num_objects = len(df)
sim_matrix = np.zeros((num_objects, num_objects))

for i in range(num_objects):
    for j in range(i + 1, num_objects):
        rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(attributes[i], attributes[j]))
        sim_matrix[i, j] = rmse
        sim_matrix[j, i] = rmse

sim_df = pd.DataFrame(sim_matrix, columns=df['object'], index=df['object'])

print("Similarity Matrix:")
print(sim_df)

sim = sim_df.values[sim_df.values != 0.0]
average_sim = sim.mean()
print(f"Average Similarity (excluding 0.0): {average_sim:.3f}")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Addition:**

If you want to calculate pairwise RMSE-based similarity:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
sim_matrix = np.sqrt(squareform(pdist(attributes, 'euclidean')))
```

**Others:** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Comment: Instead of looping like this, consider using slices like `series[:-1], series[1:]`